# How did I cause gcc to produce a .bundle instead of a .so?

Tags: c, ruby, macos, gcc, shared-libraries

I'm trying to write a Ruby extension, and I've been successfully compiling my `nmatrix.so` shared object file all day. But then, suddenly, it starts producing `nmatrix.bundle` instead, without any `.so` file at all.

It's not giving me any linker errors, so I can't imagine why this would be. I also didn't change anything in [my `Makefile` or `extconf.rb`](https://gist.github.com/1598646). I've been consistently using Ruby 1.9.3p0 through rvm.

I've tried doing a `git stash save` with my work for the day and compiling something I *know* should work without linker errors (something that produced a .so) earlier. Unfortunately, that too produces a `.bundle` file.

Clearly I have done something -- perhaps installed something inadvertently -- which has changed some critical GCC setting. This is totally possible, as I spent most of the day trying to get LAPACK and ATLAS to build, and also installed homebrew at some point.

I have discovered that there is a work-around. I change these two lines:

```
DLLIB = $(TARGET).bundle
# ...
LDSHARED = $(CC) -dynamic -bundle
```

to

```
DLLIB = $(TARGET).so
# ...
LDSHARED = $(CC) -dynamic
```

And then the library compiles and loads correctly. However, I haven't the faintest what I changed in `extconf.rb` (or elsewhere) which would have caused it to auto-generate this Makefile with `.bundle` files instead of `.so`.

The question is: how exactly did I cause this, and what do I do to restore it?

Comment: Can you include your `Makefile`?

Comment: Done. The Makefile is auto-generated using `rvm ruby extconf.rb`, so I have included `extconf.rb` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as if the problem comes from use of the LLVM gcc, which doesn't play well with Xcode 4.2.

I have regular gcc installed, so I reinstall Ruby as follows:

```
export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
rvm install 1.9.3
```

Most directions seem to say use `rvm install 1.9.3 --enable-shared` instead, but that additional flag seems to be the source of the problem.

In any case, it seems that I can now load `.bundle` files.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as "Accepted" if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The [C extensions RubyGems Guide](http://guides.rubygems.org/c-extensions/) has an overview of the building process.

The critical lines in your `extconf.rb` file are near the ends:

```
require "mkmf"
# ...
create_makefile("nmatrix")
```

This builds the `Makefile` for you. The `Makefile` is built using configuration values stored in the `RbConfig::CONFIG[]` array; the configuration value you're most interested in is `RbConfig::CONFIG['DLEXT']`:

```
$ ruby -e "require 'rbconfig'; puts RbConfig::CONFIG['DLEXT'];"
so
```

To easily see the entire configuration, look for the `rbconfig.rb` file; mine is located in `/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb`, and I'll include the first few lines here:

```
# This file was created by mkconfig.rb when ruby was built.  Any
# changes made to this file will be lost the next time ruby is built.

module Config
  RUBY_VERSION == "1.8.7" or
    raise "ruby lib version (1.8.7) doesn't match executable version (#{RUBY_VERSION})"

  TOPDIR = File.dirname(__FILE__).chomp!("/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux")
  DESTDIR = '' unless defined? DESTDIR
  CONFIG = {}
  CONFIG["DESTDIR"] = DESTDIR
  CONFIG["INSTALL"] = '/usr/bin/install -c'
  CONFIG["EXEEXT"] = ""
  CONFIG["prefix"] = (TOPDIR || DESTDIR + "/usr")
  ...
  CONFIG["DLEXT"] = "so"
  CONFIG["LDSHARED"] = "$(CC) -shared"
  CONFIG["CCDLFLAGS"] = " -fPIC"
  ...
```

So, some version of your `rbconfig.rb` file has been built when another version of Ruby was built that suggested that dynamically linked extensions should have a different extension. This might be a feature of `rvm` (which I still need to learn more about) or this might be a difference between Apple-supplied Ruby vs self-compiled Ruby. You can see in the comment header of the file that you could easily make the change in `rbconfig.rb` yourself -- but it will be blown away the next time you rebuild or install a differently-built Ruby.

(Incidentally, I thought the extension was [`.dylib`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/UsingDynamicLibraries.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002182-SW10), but it's been a while since I've used OS X, too.)

Comment: You rock! I'll try this out next time I'm on my MBA. Thank you very much.

Comment: Okay, so compilation works now -- but `rake compile` still fails, apparently on the copy operation:

    `rake aborted!
    No such file or directory - tmp/x86_64-darwin11.2.0/nmatrix/1.9.3/nmatrix.bundle`

I've already changed `rbconfig.rb`, so I'm not sure where to look.